# second highest salary in each department

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find the second highest salary in each department.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE employees
( 
    ID int NOT NULL,
    NAME char(50) NOT NULL,
    departmentid int,
    salary int 
);
```

Sample records:

```
/*departmentid =1 */
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (1, 'Max', 1, 90000);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (2, 'Joe', 1, 70000);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (3, 'Randy', 1, 70000);

/*departmentid =2 */
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (4, 'Henry', 2, 80000);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (5, 'SAM', 2, 60000);

/*departmentid =3 */
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (6, 'Janet', 3, 69000);
```

My query:

```
SELECT departmentid, 
    NAME, 
    salary 
FROM   
    (
        SELECT 
            departmentid, 
            NAME, 
            salary, 
            Dense_rank()OVER (partition BY departmentid 
                          ORDER BY salary DESC) AS Rank, 
             Count(1)OVER(partition BY departmentid) AS cnt 
        FROM   
            employees
    )t 
WHERE  
    t.rank = 2 
    OR ( t.rank = 1 
         AND cnt = 1 )
```

The output I am getting is as below;

```
departmentid   NAME    salary

1              Joe      70000

1              Randy    70000

2              SAM      60000

3              Janet    69000
```

**My expected output  is**

```
departmentid   NAME    salary

1              Joe      70000

1              Randy    70000

2              SAM      60000

3              NULL     NULL
```

As there is only one record for departmentid=3, it should return null.

What is wrong with this query? Any other ways to achieve this result?

I've also included a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bb5e1/14).

Comment: Please read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). Your question should *contain your question*, not a link to some other place where your actual question is to be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used two [CTEs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql).

The first returns a list of every department.  You'll need this to ensure departments with less than 2 salaries are included in the final result.

The second ranks each employee within their department.

Finally, I've used a [left outer join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/outer-joins) to maintain the complete list of departments.

```
WITH Department AS
(
  -- Returns a list of the departments.
  SELECT 
    departmentid
  FROM
    employees
  GROUP BY
    departmentid
),
EmployeeRanked AS
(
  SELECT
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY departmentid ORDER BY salary DESC) AS [Rank],
    departmentid,
    NAME,
    salary
  FROM
    employees
)
SELECT 
  er.Rank,
  d.departmentid,
  er.NAME,
  er.salary
FROM 
  Department AS d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN EmployeeRanked AS er    ON er.departmentid = d.departmentid
                                            AND er.[Rank] = 2
;
```

Returns

```
Rank    departmentid    NAME    salary
2       1               Joe     70000
2       1               Randy   70000
2       2               SAM     60000
(null)  3               (null)  (null)
```

Answer (score 3):

ROW_NUMBER() and select = 2

```
   ;WITH salary AS
    (
     [RN] = SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY departmentid ORDER BY salary),*
    FROM <table>
    )
    SELECT 
    *
    FROM salary
    WHERE [RN] = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub query as i wrote here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bb5e1/26

```
 with ranks as(
 SELECT departmentid, 
       salary,
       row_number() over (partition by (departmentid) order by salary desc) as rank
FROM   employees
   )
   Select * 
   from ranks
Where ranks.rank = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a simple way:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (Select top 2 * FROM employees order by salary desc ) e Order by salary asc
```

Edit: this returns only the 2nd highest overall

Comment: When I run this query it returns Henry, who is the top earner in department 2.

Comment: My mistake it returns the overall 2nd highest

Answer (score 0):

If the departmentid having only one row, and if you consider that also. Then

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
  select [rank] = dense_rank() over(
    partition by departmentid
    order by departmentid, salary desc
  ), *
  from employees
)
select ID, NAME, departmentid, salary from cte
where [rank] = 2
union all
select max(ID), max(NAME), departmentid, max(salary)
from cte
group by departmentid
having count([rank]) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get correct answer by just removing below code from your code

```
OR ( t.rank = 1 
         AND cnt = 1 )
```

also main table should be left join from this result to get null in rest of columns

Answer (score 0):

```
--First approach
select e.dept, max(e.salary) salary
FROM 
EMPLOYEE e
outer apply  (
    select dept, MAX(salary) salary
    FROM EMPLOYEE a
    where e.dept = a.dept
    GROUP BY DEPT
) o 
where e.salary < o.salary
GROUP by e.dept
GO

--Second Approach
SELECT DEPT, MAX(SALARY)
FROM (
    SELECT DEPT, SALARY
    FROM EMPLOYEE
    EXCEPT
    SELECT DEPT, MAX(SALARY) SALARY
    FROM EMPLOYEE
    GROUP BY DEPT
) A
GROUP BY A.DEPT
GO
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**